# Find and scroll to (or highlight) some text on page

Tags: javascript

I want to find text on page and scroll to it. Eg finds the first word of the match and injects hidden element next to it with the purpose of scrolling to that point.

**Here's the problem:** text might span multiple paragraphs, and some words of the "needle" text might be represented by links, headers, etc.

Not sure how to start tackling this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/blob/gh-pages/dist/bootstrap-toc.js

Might not seem related on first glance but if you dig into how the headings are searched for and selected you might be able to adapt it for your "find text on page" use case.

Creating a hidden element that you can then scroll to is already mostly implemented in this project as well so hopefully you find this useful.